# How do I display other database values not included in the datagridiew into another form in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a datagridview with rows only showing the name and id of an employee. When I double clicked the data from the datagridview, another form will show up showing the data of that employee and other values not included in the datagridview. How would I do that? Thanks.

Comment: get the ID of the user in the selected row in the grid. pass that ID to the new form when you create it / open it. Use that ID in your query to select the rest of the data from the DB. Bind the result to your grid. It's a common Summary/Details view pattern. What have you researched or tried so far? Are you facing a specific problem, or have you just not looked into it yet?

Comment: i looked but am confused as to how i will construct it.

Comment: what precisely is confusing you? I outlined several steps there in my comment. Which one is the problem? What specifically don't you understand? You should find if you research each step individually it's quite simple and easy to discover. Then you put all the small, easier-to-understand parts together to make the solution. (And that, essentially, is the secret of programming, really.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I didn't misunderstand, you are populating a DataGridView selecting from your Employees table only ID and Name.

If you wanna other values that are not included in that DataGridView, in another form by double clicking the cell, you have to add an event named `dataGridViewName_CellDoubleClick`.

Inside the event you have to retrieve Employee Id that has been clicked:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
```

Doing so you are selecting the Cell[0] (in my case Employee Id) of the row that has been clicked.

To pass the Id to another form is simple:

Form where you want to show the other values:

```
int EmployeeId;

public Form2(int employeeId)
{
    EmployeeId = employeeId;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Inside the double click event after getting the Id:

```
Form2 form = new Form2(id);
form.Show();
```

Once you have Employee's Id, you can get other values from the Database.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you give me an idea how to construct it? I'm sorry i'm a newbie

Comment: i mean how do i use the retrieved id?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment! Once the id is retrieved, you can simply pass it as parameter to create the new form to show the other values. Doing so, you have to add the parameter to form's constructor though (look at the public Form2 code in the answer)

Comment: i've got it thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

There is a property of a `DataGridViewRow` called `Tag` which you can use to store any object - you could use this to store the full collection of properties for the Employee and pass that to the other form when the row is double-clicked